# Warning: glob(): Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters

Tags: symfony, sylius

I just update Sylius with composer and exec `php bin/console server:run` and I've 
 get this error:

> Warning: glob(): Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260
>   characters in
>   C:\project\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_user.yml
>   (which is being imported from
>   "C:\project\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml").

Composer update log is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 9 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/symfony (v3.3.5 => v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating doctrine/cache (v1.6.1 => v1.6.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating doctrine/common (v2.7.2 => v2.7.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.6.2 => v2.6.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sensiolabs/security-checker (v4.0.4 => v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating payum/payum-bundle (2.2.0 => 2.2.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating doctrine/dbal (v2.5.12 => v2.5.13): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sylius/sylius (v1.0.0-beta.2 => v1.0.0-beta.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpspec/phpspec (3.4.0 => 3.4.2): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I work in windows 10 platform. I've update my regedit and allow long path and restart my cumputer (with this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try any of the solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218964/install-sylius-symfony3-on-windows).
I had a similar problem (installing Sylius 1.0.0 beta 3), tried replacing line 86 in `vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader`
(`import` function) to
`if (is_string($resource) && false === strpos($resource, "\n") && strlen($resource) !== $i = strcspn($resource, '*?{[')) {`
and was able to continue.
A hack, but what can you do. Windows suffers from these problems, unlike Unix OS.